# Make an image follow the frame size

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm using Java Swing to make a GUI.

I need to present to the user some information printed on images (which are generated at run time as `BufferedImage` objects).

What I am doing: I put a `JPanel` on my `JFrame`, and when the system calls the `paint(Graphics g)` method I draw the image on `g` -> `(g.drawImage(buffImg,0,0,null))`.

The thing I do not like is: When I resize the frame, the image remains the same, I only expand the field of view.  I'd like instead to make the image "stretch" with the frame when I resize it.

Is there an efficient way of doing it?  (I thought I could create a new resized image, the size of the frame, each time I refresh the graphics, but I'm updating the image several times per second, so it would be a really heavy task..)

Comment: 1) Use camelCase for attributes. 2) For custom painting in `JPanel`, override `paintComponent()`, for custom painting in `JFrame` ..just don't.  Use a `JComponent` or `JPanel` 3) *"it would be a really heavy task"* Profiling beats speculation.

Comment: 1) right :D 2) that's what i do, i only draw on the jpanel, but since the gui won't refresh the image when i update it, i force the update like this: `g = panel.getGraphics(); panel.paint(g);`  ...  not elegant but works just fine :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
g.drawImage(BuffImg,0,0,null):
```

To:

```
g.drawImage(BuffImg,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this):
```

Comment: really can't belive it was that easy..
i had read of course the javadoc for the Graphics class, but i misunderstood:
i thought "Draws as much of the specified image as has already been scaled to fit inside the specified rectangle." was meaning "draws only a portion of the image"
thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries.  Glad you had checked the Java Docs (they are a great resource, but there are times I've misunderstood what I read from them), and glad you got it sorted.  :-)